# Xcode time difference in days, hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: xcode, date, time, timer, difference

First of all: I want to say happy new year to everybody reading this!! May 2015 be a great year for all of us :-).

I'm busy with making a function which calculates the time difference between two dates. To be more precise: the time between a time and date given and the current time and date.
So the user selects a date in the past and then the program shows the time difference between the given date and todays date in a timer like so: "hh:mm:ss"

It works okay and updates every second when i select a time of todays date (01-01-2015 10:00:00), but when selecting a date and time in the past (31-12-2014 17:00:00) and compare it to todays date where the time is earlier than yesterday (01-01-2015 14:01:01), it gives me a negative time like a sort of countdown timer: -2:-59:-59.

But i want it to show the opposite of it: 21:01:01 and if possible if it exceeds the 24:00:00, just count on. For example 25:12:39.

This is the code that calculates the difference:

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"30-12-2014 %@", startedTime]];
NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"31-12-2014 %@", [self getCurrentTime]]];
NSTimeInterval interval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];

int hours = (int)interval / 3600;             // integer division to get the hours part
int minutes = (interval - (hours*3600)) / 60; // interval minus hours part (in seconds) divided by 60 yields minutes
int seconds = (interval - (hours*3600) - (minutes*60)); // interval minus hours part (in seconds) divided by 60 yields minutes

NSString *timeDiff = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
_workingTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timeDiff];
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
```

Try after this change of the format string!

And this.. finally.

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
if( interval  < 0 ) {
  interval = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
}
```

[More about date formats here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: You're awesome. Can't believe i didn't see that. Especially the first part. Thanks it works now!